# can I become a monk with schizophrenia?

Tags: monk

can I become a monk if i have schizophrenia?
I have to take a shot every two weeks and I do hear voices every once in a while

Answer (score 1):

Householder Goudakid, interested,

whether a Bhikkhu gives one ordination as Samanera (Novice monk) or the Community of a particular Sangha of Bhikkhus also higher ordination is aside of some limitations the Buddha gave, total up the Bhikkhu(s), an act of compassion and not something anybody whould ever have a right to. Thats importand. And the Sangha should be never seen as common social institution for a living.

Whether one goes for and gets ordained, even at good or bad communities is, how ever a matter of Upanissaya (strong conditions = dependent on strong paccaya, kamma, of past and present).

There would be limitations for higher ordinations in regard of grave illness since hard for the community to look after sick and not pleasing for supporters. But even if the case that one gets ordained, such would be not invalid, yet a wrong doing for the one who gives ordination.

As for novice, there are less formal questions which would limit aside of the always invalid criterias.

My person could not even generally say that hearing voices might be an illness at all categorical.

As long as not real "stupid" or holding grave wrong views, there is less limitation and the best way to get ones own possibility and the possibility of the Bhikkus known is simply to start (if allowed) to live with them and serve at monasteries, taking min eigth precepts.

Usually good monks would not close any possibility and seek for the best way for one, yet are limited in suggesting and it requires all that one would ask for what ever one desires. So own initative is needed and wrong shame (to do good things) may be strong hindrance, since nobody would invite you to make good choices and ask for accessing good areas and giving.

The more honest one approaches and speaks, the more wise people have possibilities to help and such is needed for the grow into the holly life.

Illness, if even a "real" one, are not for sure and nothing heals more than precepts and the holly life and my person would nothing but encourage to such, even if "only just" in white and serving the Tripple Gems. Don't householder wast long time and struggle around with doubts and go after a blessed good mindstate and seek for it, since good mindstates are seldom and not lasting.

Much success and if having further questions he may also feel welcome [here](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=forum), where are also not so public areas.

There are some related answers als well:

- [[Q&A] Meditation for Psychosis - Can Dhamma help for mental problems](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,2120.msg9376.html#msg9376)
- When is the best time for ordination?

> Now. Don't waste time. Also good Intentions are not for sure.

- [Mental ilness, causes and apaya realms](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/24569/11235)

*(Note that this is not given for trade, stacks, exchange or entertainment but as means for kusala deeds out of this wheel)*